# Apache-Camel Accessing header values within string-template

Tags: apache-camel, stringtemplate

my problem is, I don't know how I can access exchange's header values inside a string-template declaration. I would like to have internationalized mail templates. The test code below ...

```
public class StringTemplateTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:start")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void testTemplating() throws Exception {
        resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("test");
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("test", "lang", "de");
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start").to("string-template:mailTemplate_$simple{in.header.lang}.tm").to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

ends in a ...

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find resource: mailTemplate_$simple{in.header.lang}.tm in classpath for URI: mailTemplate_$simple{in.header.lang}.tm
```

I would expect, the string-template is lookig for **mailTemplate_de.tm**.

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `.to("component:xyz")` endpoints are evaluated at the time the route is built - they are not dynamic and won't pick up `${}` properties.

Instead you need to use `recipientList`, like this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .recipientList(simple("string_template:mailTemplate_${in.header.lang}.tm"))
    .to("mock:result")
```

Comment: See this FAQ about dynamic to: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html